# how do i use this select

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

how do I use this query and import the results into the products table external code field?. Can someone help?

```
SELECT *  , right(prod.productcode, len(prod.productcode) - LEN(sup.prefix) ) AS ExternalCoode
FROM MSLStore1_Products prod  ,supplier sup
WHERE prod.suppid = 9217 AND prod.SgpID = 123 and sup.supno = prod.suppid
```

Comment: It would help if you stopped writing that bad implicit syntax. Hoever, if we are to show you how to write an insert, we need more data, such as the table structure we are going to insert into. Or did you really need an update to an existing records or a merge where you insert if not htere and update if there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update MSLStore1_Products set ExternalCoode = right(MSLStore1_Products.productcode, len(MSLStore1_Products.productcode) - LEN(supplier.prefix) )
From 
MSLStore1_Products , supplier WHERE MSLStore1_Products.suppid = 9217 AND MSLStore1_Products.SgpID = 123 and supplier.supno = MSLStore1_Products.suppid
```

I have always been caught out by aliases in joins in updates (because I don't think you can alias the target of the update), which is why I replaced the aliases with full names.

Comment: Actually you can alias the target table and you can even reference it by alias after the `UPDATE` keyword: `UPDATE prod SET ... FROM MSLStore1_Products prod, supplier sup ...`.

Comment: what do you mean mate can you right an example in pusedo code